# Internal Server Error - Azure App Service Custom Controller

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure Mobile App Service (not old mobileservice), with multiple custom controllers, and the flow works perfectly.

Today an error occurred about `Internal Server Error`.

I attached the debugger an stepped through the code, and the controller gets to the end without any errors and hits the return `Ok`. Therefore I have not been able to find the root. But the client then gets the error that there is an internal server error.

I make a server call like:

```
DTO.UserDTO uploadImage = await ((App)Application.Current).MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<DTO.UsernameCheckDto, DTO.UserDTO>("user/blobStorageRetrieval", new DTO.UsernameCheckDto() { Username = ((App)Application.Current).InGameUserName }, System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, null);
```

The custom controller ends with:

```
return Ok(new UserDTO()
{
    MicrosoftId = stable_sid,
    Username = stable_users.Username,
    playerNames = playerNames,
    playerScores = playerInts,
    isCreated = true,
    bestScore = stable_users.bestRunnerScore,
    statsInformation = _statsInformation,
});
```

I have verified that all the variables are initialized. The Type UserDTO is referenced from the same `Portable Library`. Can anybody hint how I can find the cause of this error? The controller has worked before without any changes.

**Generic Error Message**

> "The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)"  string

Response

> {StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
>   {
>     Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
>     Date: Fri, 30 Sep 2016 17:37:57 GMT
>     X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>     Content-Length: 36
>     Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   }}  System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage

stack

> StackTrace    "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__24.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__26.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.d__69.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.d__63 2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at Stonegaard_endless_runner.MainPage.d__7.MoveNext()"   string

## solution proposal

Searching Sid oh stackoverflow. And found an issue from 2 years ago. [Web API converted to Azure Mobile Service not serializing all properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24295228/web-api-converted-to-azure-mobile-service-not-serializing-all-properties)

I will try this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to add:

```
httpConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include;
httpConfig.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Include;
```

to `Startup.MobileApp.cs` in the method `ConfigureMobileApp`.