# Azure Service App [Mobileservice] - Custom error response

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps, azure-app-api

I've been working on an app and sometimes during my coding I receive 500 Internal Server Error with no content, which isn't really what it's suppose to show. I wrote a code to test the error response in the controller as following:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("TryCatch")]
    public IHttpActionResult TestCatch()
    {
        try
        {
            object obj = null;
            int i = (int) obj;
            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return InternalServerError(e);
        }
    }
```

When I try this locally, I do receive the information regarding the error that I wished for. As for in production, all I see is (in postman) {
  "message": "An error has occurred."
} and the status code.

I've looked around and found what I thought would be solution to my problem: [Internal Server Error - Azure App Service Custom Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39797262/internal-server-error-azure-app-service-custom-controller) but it wasn't.

And adding `<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="passThrough">` or `<customErrors mode="On"/>` or anything in web.config doesn't help either.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the custom errors mode to Off instead of On.

```
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
```

And change IncludeErrorDetailPolicy property to Always in WebApiConfig.cs file(Azure Mobile Service) or Startup.cs file(Azure Mobile App).

```
config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
```

After that, I can get the detail exception message from the exceptionMessage property.

```
{"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.","exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","stackTrace":""}
```

Comment: Thank you sir! `config.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;` that part solved my problem!